# Dynamically reference cells in a linked book without INDIRECT or VBA?

Tags: excel

I'm looking accomplish something like the following:

```
=SUM(some_function('[linked workbook.xlsx]Sheet1!', ADDRESS(1, A1), ADDRESS(1, A2)))
```

Where the column numbers are stored in A1 and A2 (for example)

I would use INDIRECT, but I can't always have a ton of files open, and unfortunately VBA is simply too time consuming to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX. With 5 in A1, this refers to Sheet1!E:E,

```
INDEX(Sheet1!A:Z, 0, A1)
```

With 8 in A1, this refers to Sheet1!H2,

```
INDEX(Sheet1!A:Z, 2, A1)
```

You've offered no specifics but this should get you started.